# Cannot deploy servlet sample GWT app to Apache Tomcat 7

Tags: gwt, tomcat, servlets, tomcat7, gwt-rpc

Original, less detailed question found here: [Cannot figure out why I cannot deploy GWT application onto Apache Tomcat 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16074224/cannot-figure-out-why-i-cannot-deploy-gwt-application-onto-apache-tomcat-7). As I was writing this, I decided to try it again and this time it worked however, the servlet in the sample Application does not seem to work. It says "Remote Procedure Call Failure" when clicking the button. Here's the list of steps i took.

Here are the list of things I tried to do in order to deploy a sample app to Apache Tomcat 7.

**Setting Up Environment**

1. Install Ubuntu 12.04 on Virtual Machine
2. Updated system
3. Install Apache Tomcat 7 from tutorial here https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-on-ubuntu-12-04.
4. Start it and go to localhost:8080 to see that it is working.

**Getting Sample Project**

1. Have GWT installed.
2. Using Eclipse Wizard, Create a new project called "SampleApp"
3. Run it once in development mode to ensure it works.
4. Compile the module. it does the whole - compiling 6 permutations etc.
5. Compile into .war file as shown here http://blog.elitecoderz.net/gwt-and-tomcat-create-war-using-eclipse-to-deploy-war-on-tomcat/2009/12/ (file is called SampleApp.war)

**Deploying**

1. Copy SampleApp.war into webapps folder in Apache Tomcat
2. The .war unzips itself and i can now access my app on localhost:8080/SampleApp/SampleApp.html.

However, now my problem is that the server-side code does not seem to work.

**The content of localhost_access_log**

> 127.0.0.1 - - [18/Apr/2013:21:03:43 -0700] "GET /SampleApp/SampleApp.html HTTP/1.1" 304 -
>   127.0.0.1 - - [18/Apr/2013:21:03:43 -0700] "GET /SampleApp/SampleApp.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
>   127.0.0.1 - - [18/Apr/2013:21:03:43 -0700] "GET /SampleApp/sampleapp/sampleapp.nocache.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
>   127.0.0.1 - - [18/Apr/2013:21:03:43 -0700] "GET /SampleApp/sampleapp/gwt/clean/clean.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
>   127.0.0.1 - - [18/Apr/2013:21:03:43 -0700] "GET /SampleApp/sampleapp/gwt/clean/images/hborder.png HTTP/1.1" 304 -
>   127.0.0.1 - - [18/Apr/2013:21:03:44 -0700] "POST /SampleApp/sampleapp/greet HTTP/1.1" 500 2773
>   127.0.0.1 - - [18/Apr/2013:21:03:44 -0700] "GET /SampleApp/sampleapp/gwt/clean/images/circles.png HTTP/1.1" 304 -
>   127.0.0.1 - - [18/Apr/2013:21:03:44 -0700] "GET /SampleApp/sampleapp/gwt/clean/images/vborder.png HTTP/1.1" 304 -

**The content of localhost.2013-04-18**

> Apr 18, 2013 8:02:05 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext
>   log INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized() Apr 18, 2013 8:02:05
>   PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log INFO:
>   SessionListener: contextInitialized() Apr 18, 2013 8:02:05 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log INFO: ContextListener:
>   attributeAdded('org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache',
>   'org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache@dc0435') Apr 18, 2013
>   8:02:16 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log INFO:
>   ContextListener: contextInitialized() Apr 18, 2013 8:02:16 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log INFO: SessionListener:
>   contextInitialized() Apr 18, 2013 8:02:16 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log INFO: ContextListener:
>   attributeAdded('org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache',
>   'org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache@113e9fd') Apr 18, 2013
>   8:02:16 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log INFO:
>   SessionListener: contextDestroyed() Apr 18, 2013 8:02:16 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log INFO: ContextListener:
>   contextDestroyed() Apr 18, 2013 8:29:48 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log INFO: SessionListener:
>   contextDestroyed() Apr 18, 2013 8:29:48 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log INFO: ContextListener:
>   contextDestroyed() Apr 18, 2013 8:30:00 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log INFO: ContextListener:
>   contextInitialized() Apr 18, 2013 8:30:00 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log INFO: SessionListener:
>   contextInitialized() Apr 18, 2013 8:30:00 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log INFO: ContextListener:
>   attributeAdded('org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache',
>   'org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache@180cb01') Apr 18, 2013
>   9:03:36 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log INFO:
>   SessionListener: contextDestroyed() Apr 18, 2013 9:03:36 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log INFO: ContextListener:
>   contextDestroyed() Apr 18, 2013 9:03:41 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log INFO: ContextListener:
>   contextInitialized() Apr 18, 2013 9:03:41 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log INFO: SessionListener:
>   contextInitialized() Apr 18, 2013 9:03:41 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log INFO: ContextListener:
>   attributeAdded('org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache',
>   'org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache@18600d6')

**GreetingService.java**

```
package com.sample.client;

import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.RemoteService;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.RemoteServiceRelativePath;

/**
 * The client side stub for the RPC service.
 */
@RemoteServiceRelativePath("greet")
public interface GreetingService extends RemoteService {
    String greetServer(String name) throws IllegalArgumentException;
}
```

**/WEB-INF/web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
              http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         version="2.5"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">

  <!-- Servlets -->
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>greetServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sample.server.GreetingServiceImpl</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>greetServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/sampleapp/greet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <!-- Default page to serve -->
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>SampleApp.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

I've changed noting after generating the project via eclipse.

As I am still trying to figure this out, it may possible have something to do with Java 1.6 and 1.7 SDK and the way tomcat interacts with them

Comment: Again, please provide logs of the error from tomcat.

Comment: i posted my access logs. hopefully this will be relevant information.

Comment: Can you please post your web.xml and the servlet path given for rpc?

Comment: it is done, Baadshash.

Answer (score 0):

Try to just compile your sample app with GWT-compile and copy content of the war directory of you project to tomcat/webapps/sample. After that check you app at url

```
http://localhost:8080/example
```

Comment: i am a little confused at what you said. i took the contents of the war file, and i made a new folder in webapps called "sample" I copied the contents of war there. the url you said doesnt work (unless you want 8080:/sample. The only thing that works currently is localhost:8080/sample/SampleApp.html. I still have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Problem with the `path`.

```
@RemoteServiceRelativePath("sampleapp/greet");

or 

@RemoteServiceRelativePath("../greet");
```

Refer @chris [Deploy GWT to Tomcat (servlet not running)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6538731/deploy-gwt-to-tomcat-servlet-not-running)

Comment: i've tried this but again no luck. wouldnt modifying the web.xml file and changing the sampleapp/greet to just /greet accomplish the same thing? in any case, that doesnt seem to work and it also breaks the GWT development run. sigh. i've tried so many combinations that i am completely lost and I have no idea what is wrong

Comment: Have you done anything related to module rename in gwt.xml http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4965596/gwt-eclipse-plugin-how-to-rename-project-along-with-gwt-xml-file-am-getting-e

Comment: i have not modified the sample project in anyway - the only thing i did was File->New-Google Project. SampleApp in the name field, com.sample in the package name. I made sure the "Generate Code" is checked and i unchecked the "Use Google APP Engine". i use the code that is generated. I then attempt to start deploying the code